# Thread.CurrentPrincipal has null details on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, adfs

We are trying to use Thred.CurrentPrincipal to get the user information. However as soon as we deploy it to Azure the CurrentPrincipal is null.

```
var td = new TokenData();

var claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;

if (claimsPrincipal != null)
{
    td.IsAuthenticated = claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    td.Name = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
    td.Email = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;
    td.Surname = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
    td.Role = claimsPrincipal.FindAll("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group")
        .Select(s=>s.Value);
}
```

I verified that ADFS is set-up correctly. It would be great if someone could point me to the pain-point of this.

**Edit:**

The CurrentPrincipal is not NULL but the details are. So we are not getting the user's name, roles and other details.

**Edit 2:**

This is what is happening on Azure:

[image: remote debugging on Azure]

[image: remote debugging on Azure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Claim Rule wasn't set-up for the ADFS record.

[image]

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to turn on User Profiles in order to get your principal to work.

To turn it on In the portal on your website go to Configuration -> App Settings and add the app setting [WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#add-user-profile-support-for-a-site) = 1.  You site needs to be in Basic or Standard mode for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that hasn't solved my problem. I will update my question with more details.

Comment: Actually let me check again as my website is in Free mode.

Comment: I can confirm that scaling the website and adding the parameter did not solve the problem.